# Exchange 2003. How can I move folders and contents from one user to another?

Tags: exchange-2003, windows-sbs

I'm the volunteer admin at a school using Windows Small Business Server 2003.

A staff member has left. We want to copy parts of the contents of her Exchange mailbox to other users. Before she left, she arranged the mail in folders. This folder goes to user 1, this folder goes to user 2 etc.

How can we do this? I'm thinking of using an IMAP client (probably Outlook Express or Thunderbird), connect to both accounts and simply copy the folders across. Is that a reasonable way to do it? Is there a better way?

We're low on CALs. We don't want to leave the old account there. We want to distribute the mail and delete it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things you can do.

First, you could export the contents to a .pst file, and open that on the computers that need access to it and copy the parts of the mailbox that you want.

Second, you could grant the people that need access to the folders access to the mailbox itself, and add it through Outlook.

In both cases, you will need to visit the destination computers to either open the .pst or connect another mailbox to that users account. The first option would allow you to dump the mail, and delete the account immediately.

Comment: +1, this is what I would do as well. As far as I know there's no options in Exchange to just copy someone's mailbox.